# Unable to print the data on console using df.show()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading kafka topic using readStream and try to display dataframe on the console.

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer)\.option("subscribe", topic_name_read)\.option("includeHeaders", "true")\.option("startingOffsets", "latest")\.load()\.select(F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data"))\.select("data.*")
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

I've encountered the following error.

```
File "C:/spark/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 494, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\spark\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__  
  File "C:/spark/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
kafka
```

The below is the printSchema of my dataframe.

```
root

 |-- id: string (nullable = true)

 |-- title: string (nullable = true)

 |-- channelId: string (nullable = true)

 |-- channelTitle: string (nullable = true)

 |-- publishedAt: timestamp (nullable = true)

 |-- statistics: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.show()
```

is an action, you have to start your streaming to be able to perform an action on your streaming Dataset from Kafka

`df.writeStream.format("console").outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination()`
should display your df